# How does one access the video link from a CalendarApp.CalendarEvent?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

There's no mention of video links in the documentation.

I created a calendar link using the Zoom addon and the build-in Meet option - neither seem to add a "tag" or any other accessible metadata to the event. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the working using the Zoom calendar add-in, but still no luck on Google Meet.

### zoom links:

You must create the meeting through the Zoom API. Zoom stores a non-authoritive copy of meeting metadata in the calendar event:

```
const event = CalendarApp.getEvent(...)
const zoomParams = event.getTag("meetingParams") // returns an object with the keys: ['topic', 'type', 'start_time', 'duration', 'end_time']
const zoomMeetingId = event.getTag("meetingId") // returns an int.
Logger.log(`meeting link: https://zoom.us/j/${link_id}`);
```

### meet links:

Thanks to the tip from DalmTo - Meet events are stored as "conferences," which are not available within the Native AppsScripts API.

You can access the links by [enabling advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services), which means configuring a GCP project. The Calendar.Event object will contain a ConferenceData object with the video link info.

IMHO - if you are going to set up API keys and whatnot, there are diminishing returns on remaining in the AppsScript tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation [Events.Insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert) you will notice that there is an option to add conference data it will create the link for you when its inserted.

[image]

Wither or not app script supports it is another question.

Comment: Appscript does not support it - but this led me to a workable answer - AppsScript now has (kinda clunky) support for the actual google apis.